# How can I retrieve a row by uuid in Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

I only have a uuid, but I don't know which table is the the row of the data located, how can I find the data by the UUID?

My direction maybe create a multiple query, since we could retrieve all tables, then we can loops all table and search by `select * from $tableName where id = $uuid`, but it might not be efficient enough, is there any shortcut or tool for this purpose?